# Better way to cater the stringlist

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code to update my table using linq to entity.

It takes two parameters one is string and string list.my linq query update the column with \r\n.

Am expecting my string list(HoursByRate) have one to five values.

For example if my string list have only one value ,in that case can i assign the rest (HoursByRate2 -5) as empty space ? or

write a separate method to cater this logic?

```
 string HoursByRate1 = HoursByRate[0].ToString();
 string HoursByRate2 = HoursByRate[1].ToString();//assign empty if no value
 string HoursByRate3 = HoursByRate[2].ToString();
 string HoursByRate4 = HoursByRate[3].ToString();
 string HoursByRate5 = HoursByRate[4].ToString();
var query = 
// var querySEVTs =
    from SEVTs in db.SEVTs
    where
    SEVTs.SESID == BookingSesid
    select SEVTs;
foreach (var SEVTs in query)
{
    SEVTs.USER3 = (HoursByRate1 + SqlFunctions.Char(10) + SqlFunctions.Char(13) + HoursByRate2 + SqlFunctions.Char(10) + SqlFunctions.Char(13) + HoursByRate3 + SqlFunctions.Char(10) + SqlFunctions.Char(13) + HoursByRate4 + SqlFunctions.Char(10) + SqlFunctions.Char(13) + HoursByRate5 + SqlFunctions.Char(10) + SqlFunctions.Char(13));
}
db.SaveChanges();
;
```

Comment: What is the question? Where exactly the problem is?

Comment: i don't have any problem, am asking suggestion to write a better way to cater one of the condition i mentioned above. if the string list doesn't contain all five values,is that a good idea to assign null for the rest ?

Comment: If you are passing a list then I think HoursByRate[1] will give an exception if it has only one element.

Comment: Or are you passing fixed length list of size 5,and have values string.Empty when there are not all five values.

Comment: @ethicallogics,my string list may contain one value or up  to five values and its not fixed length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string value = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
           string str = " ";
           if (i < HoursByRate.Count())
               str = HoursByRate[i];
           value += str + ((char)10).ToString() + ((char)13).ToString();
       }

foreach (var SEVTs in query)
{
    SEVTs.USER3 = value;
 }
```

Comment: ,i tried with switch statement and tried yours also, i got the exception "This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities."

Comment: " SqlFunctions.Char(10) + SqlFunctions.Char(13)" this is not recoganized

Comment: Simply replace it with AScii value of 10 and 13.

Comment: you mean like this " value += str + SqlFunctions.Char(012) + SqlFunctions.Char(015);"

Comment: If I am not wrong you are using SqlFunctions.Char() to get the char value of   ASCII 10 and 13 ,You can replace it with (char)10 and (char)13. I have updated the answer.

Comment: SqlFunctions.Char(10) and (13) for carriage return and new line.

Comment: I have updated the answer.(char)10 will also give the same value but apply ToString() so that you can concat it to String.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be having this problem in the first place - rethink your database schema:

Use a table (e.g. "hourlyRates") that has a foreign key on your user table and a single hourly rate. There can be multiple rows for each user (or whatever your main table is), in your case one to five. To get all hourly rates for a given user you can then join the user table with the hourlyRate table based on the user id.

Comment: true but database is third party ,so we don't have any control of it. i have to do it thru front end :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do what the String.Join method does?

```
SEVTs.USER3 = String.Join(SqlFunctions.Char(10) + SqlFunctions.Char(13), HoursByRate)
```

Comment: ,am excatly trying to do what "ethicallogics" mentioned above but i used switch statement but both are failed